# PHPMailer MySQL Send mail with database infos

Tags: mysql, phpmailer

i'm trying to send mail with database informations with PHPMailer.
My request if very specific and i don't understand how to do what i want..

Basically i have a table in my database in which i have email adresses and other datas and i want to send these datas to only these specific email adresses

I tried first to select all my data, put it in a array and then select all the email adresses using a while loop but it would send every datas to every email adresses

Here's my SQL :

```
$sql = SELECT info1, info2, info3, info4, info5, entreprise.nom as entreprise_name, entreprise.mail_commercial as mail FROM table JOIN entreprise ON equipement.entreprise_id = entreprise.id WHERE info1 < DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 6 MONTH) AND info1 IS NOT NULL or info2 < DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH) AND info2 IS NOT NULL
```

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
```

And here's my PHPMailer :

```
$datas = array();
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $datas[] = $row;
    }
}
         $body = "Hello ";
         
         foreach ($datas as $data){
            $mail->AddAddress($data['mail']);
            $mail->Subject = "Test";
            $body .= $data['info1'] . ' ';
            $body .= $data['info2']. ' ';
            $body .= $data['info3']. ' ';
            $body .= $data['info4']. ' ';
            $body .= $data['info5']. ' ';
            $body .= $data['entreprise_name']. ' '."</br>";
        }
                $body .= "";
        $mail->Body = $body;
$mail->send();
```

Comment: What **exactly** is not working with that code? What have you tried to resolve the problem?

Comment: As i described my code is working, but not the way i want it to.
I want to send my data to only email specified in my database, like first 5 send to one adress, next 50 to another one but not the 55 records to the 2 adresses

Comment: And what di you try to resolve that? Where's the code to put the data into an array first?

Comment: I edited sorry i put up wrong code

Comment: I don't see any logic in that code that puts the recipients into batches of 50 each. Maybe you need to add that first?

Comment: Yes i want it to be dynamics, to send the values to the good mail adress not every, i don't want to go back to the code and make seperate loop for each email adresses

Comment: And what's your question about this? Why not write some code to achieve that?

Comment: Did you look at [the mailing list example provided with PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/mailing_list.phps) that shows how to do this correctly?